# Why isn't my Apache Tomcat server starting up? Unix

Tags: apache, unix, tomcat

I'm trying to start my apache tomcat server on OS 10.10.

Here is my terminal output when running startup.sh

```
ChristophersMBP:~ christopher$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Users/christopher/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Users/christopher/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Users/christopher/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/Home
Using CLASSPATH:       /Users/christopher/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Users/christopher/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

Here is my environmental setup file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export PATH="/Library/Java/Home/bin:$PATH"
export CLASSPATH=.:/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar:/tomcat/lib/jsp-api.jar:/tomcat/lib/el-api.jar:/tomcat/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar
export ANT_HOME=/tomcat
export TOMCAT_HOME=/tomcat
export CATALINA_HOME=/tomcat
```

I have tried running http://localhost:8080/ in Chrome to only get the "This webpage is not available" message. I receive no popup window or lag after calling the startup.sh, only that output in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the server is running and listening:

```
    ps -fe | grep tomcat
    netstat -tupan | grep 8080
```

Check out my Tomcat Init script as well: https://gist.github.com/miglen/5590986